# accessing instance_variable from Rails view in after_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to access an instance_variable (or any permutation of a variable) in an after_action. For example (in slim):

```
- @main_show_cache_hit = 'bees'
- cache [@lawyer] do
  - @main_show_cache_hit = 'double-bees'
```

and have in my controller:

```
  after_action :memcached_stats, only: :show
  
  ...

  def show
    # can put @main_show_cache_hit = "birds" 
  end

  ...      
  def memcached_stats
    Rails.logger.info "------ START memcached_stats -------"
    Rails.logger.info "---#{@main_show_cache_hit}-----"
    Rails.logger.info "------ END memcached_stats -------"
  end
```

but this isn't working - how could I access this variable?